# Xampp problem,can't start apache

Tags: apache-2.2, iis-7, xampp

I know that there are like 1000 posts about this problem,but non of them help me.

I have skype, and I'm using another port.
I think that I don't have IIS because I can't find it into services.
And when I try to listen ports with netstat, I can't see that any app is using port 80

And still I can't apache start.

I have Windows 7.And didn't sleep all night because of this.

Comment: What's the error message when you execute 'httpd -k start' from the command line (run cmd.exe)? Could try another WAMP package: WampDeveloper, WampServer, etc.

Answer (score 1):

With XAMPP (and apache in general) you should check the error logs. They will provide a good starting point for diagnosing your problem. For me, there have been times when XAMPP wouldn't start apache because the httpd.conf file was misconfigured or the php.ini file was misconfigured (usually because I copied them from a previous install).

The error log is located at:
C:\Program Files (x86){XAMPP Directory}\apache\logs\error.log

You may also want to check the Event Viewer for any addition information.
Control Panel > Admininistrative Tools > Event Viewer

Comment: I have take a look at error log before I have ask here, and there is nothing, there was several days ago some notice,but nothing today.

Comment: I only had windows critacl update.It looks like that is crashing apache.

Comment: A few suggestions in that case: a) ensure you checked the right error.log (taken for granted, but important); try xampp-portcheck.exe; and try to start from apache_start.bat; also check task manager - is the process there (and just another problem?).

Comment: A few more ideas: check skype if you use it - it may listen on port 80; try a vanilla (unmodified) copy of XAMPP - using the default php.ini, httpd.conf, and httpd-ssl.conf files; and try to change the listen directive in your httpd.conf file to something other than port 80 and see if it works.

Comment: First I have check is there problem with skype. I can't start port checker it just doesn't want to start, and I have try to install again xampp,but still port checker just display black cmd win and close, I have also try to start it from cmd,but same thing, port checker just show black cmd win and close. I have restore my win before that critical update and now xampp works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem some time ago. In my case, the Web Deployment Tool was started as a service and it didn't let XAMPP to start the Apache in the port 80. Therefore, please check if you have the Web Deployment Tool service started on your machine: Start-> search for Services -> then look for Web Deployment Tool as see if it's started. If it is started, then right click on it and stop that service. After that, it should work. (this works only if Web Deployment Tool service is started).